# regex help + java

Tags: java, regex

```
"Rupees,SIN_10_2,SIN_1000".replaceAll("SIN(\\w*?)","FSIN$1");

output : Rupees,FSIN_10_2,FSIN_1000
```

I want FSIN infront of Rupees as well and This Rupees can be either start of text or end.

So out put like this

```
Expected output : FSIN_Rupees,FSIN_10_2,FSIN_1000
```

Comment: What does *and This Rupees can be either start of text or end* mean? Please add more test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for this regex:

```
(Rupees)|SIN_
```

and replace by:

```
FSIN_$1
```

This regex uses alternation to match either `Rupees` or `SIN_`. It groups `Rupees` in a captured group. Replacement is `FSIN_$1` to get the desired output.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dXn5uH/1)

In Java:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("(Rupees)|SIN_", "FSIN_$1");
//=> FSIN_Rupees,FSIN_10_2,FSIN_1000
```

Comment: `Rupees,SIN_10_2,SIN_1000,Rupees` will be replaced by `FSIN_Rupees,FSIN_10_2,FSIN_1000,FSIN_Rupees`